# Find out block size of a device

Tags: size, block

I am trying to find out the block size of a file system. I found these 2 commands:

```
    [root@node1 test]# stat -fc %s .         
    4096
    [root@node1 test]# blockdev --getbsz /dev/mapper/node1_test
    512
```

Why is the result different? Which is the correct one?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's likely that both answers are correct. It's just that `blockdev --getbsz` returns the result in bytes. Your `stat` command must be returning bits.. So 512 X 8 = 4096.

It seems that the result of `stat` would only show in bytes with that format specifier if it was not a filesystem. See the note about the formats on [this page for](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) `stat`.

Reference for [blockdev](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blockdev.8.html).